# I have a null-pointer exception and don't know how to fix it

Tags: java, swing, nullpointerexception

I've tried going to the [original Null Pointer Exception question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it), but it didn't help.  Here is the first and second line of the stack trace:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at Client.SpriteField.paintComponent(SpriteField.java:30)
```

So this is telling me that it is in the package "Client", the class "SpriteField", and the method "paintComponent" right?  Here is the code in the class SpriteField:

```
package Client;

import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;

import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class SpriteField extends JPanel 
{
    RoundSprite mSprite;
    public void CreateSpriteAt(float tX, float tY, int tWidth, int tHeight, int tRotation) 
    {
        mSprite = new RoundSprite();
        mSprite.SetPosition(tX, tY);
        mSprite.SetSpriteWidth(tWidth);
        mSprite.SetSpriteHeight(tHeight);
        mSprite.SetSpriteRotation(tRotation);
    }
    public void paintComponent (Graphics g)
    {
        if(g != null)
        {
            super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
        AffineTransform tOldTransform = g2.getTransform();

        mSprite.DrawSprite(g2);

        g2.setTransform(tOldTransform);
        }
    }

}
```

It might have been just a careless mistake, but I can't seem to find it. Please help, thanks for your time.

EDIT: As asked, here is the main method:

```
final SpriteField mSpritePanel = new SpriteField();
mSpritePanel.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() 
{
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e)
    {
        float tX = e.getX();
        float tY = e.getY();
        if(tTextWidth.getText() == null)
        {
            tTextWidth.setText("50");
        }
        int tIntWidth = Integer.parseInt(tTextWidth.getText());
        if(tIntWidth == 0)
        {
            tIntWidth = 50;
        }
        if(tTextHeight.getText() == null)
        {
            tTextHeight.setText("50");
        }
        int tIntHeight = Integer.parseInt(tTextHeight.getText());
        if(tIntHeight == 0)
        {
            tIntHeight = 50;
        }
        int tRotate = Integer.parseInt(tTextRotation.getText());
        mSpritePanel.CreateSpriteAt(tX, tY, tIntWidth, tIntHeight, tRotate); 
        mSpritePanel.repaint();
    }
});
```

Comment: Check if you are calling paintComponent() before calling createSpriteAt() ? Better include your main method too.

Comment: Point out line no 50 please

Comment: Which line is line number 30 in the source file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not calling `CreateSpriteAt` until much later, after the component is already on screen. The first time it gets to `mSprite.DrawSprite(g2);` it will of course blow up with an NPE because the `mSprite` field is initially null.

The simple fix is to not try to draw the sprite when the variable is null:

```
if (mSprite != null) mSprite.DrawSprite(g2);
```

However, since you have named this class `SpriteField`, perhaps a sprite list is what you really want, rather than a single sprite?

```
public class SpriteField extends JPanel {
    final List<RoundSprite> sprites = new ArrayList<>();

    public void CreateSpriteAt(float tX, float tY, int tWidth, int tHeight, int tRotation) {
        RoundSprite s = new RoundSprite();
        s.SetPosition(tX, tY);
        s.SetSpriteWidth(tWidth);
        s.SetSpriteHeight(tHeight);
        s.SetSpriteRotation(tRotation);
        sprites.add(s);
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
        AffineTransform originalTransform = g2.getTransform();

        for (RoundSprite s : sprites) {
            s.DrawSprite(g2);
            g2.setTransform(originalTransform);
        }
    }
}
```

P.S. Please consider following standard Java naming conventions!

Answer (score 4):

Here is the issue

```
mSprite.DrawSprite(g2); // you need to initialize mSprite
```

But here `mSprite` is `null`.

You can find this kind of mistakes easily by debugging.

Comment: Manually counting I don't get that line as number 30, instead I get `g2.setTransform(tOldTransform);`.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg `g2` can't be `null` unless the OP is calling `paintComponent` and passing a `null` value to it...